# How does "You'll See" work, exactly?

Tags: penny-arcade-3

The Delusionist pin has an ability, unlocked at a fairly low level, called "You'll See."  The description is:

> Does Nothing?

However, I've heard rumors that the more I use it, the more likely it is that something will happen when I "cast" it.

How does this work exactly, and what are the potential rewards?  I'm trying to figure out if this is worth the effort.